# Simple contact form failing to send

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have a simple contact form that is failing to send, I'm new to PHP so it's most likely I have forgotten something or the code is wrong. I understand that there are many questions on here around the same subject but I'm unsure about my code.

I'm getting the error message: Undefined index: send in \mail.php on line 31

---

HTML

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>form</title>

</head>
<body>
  <h2>Contact Form</h2>
<form id="form_id" name="form_name" action="mail.php" method="post">

  <div>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required/>
  </div>
<div>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
  </div>
<div>
<input type="number" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Phone" required/>
  </div>

<textarea name="message" type="text" id="message" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
  </div>

<div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

PHP

---

```
<?php

$to = 'test@gmail.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];


$body = <<<EMAIL

This is a message for your website.

Name: $name
Email: $email
Tel: $tel
Message: $message

EMAIL;

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Bob <$to>, Bob <$to>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Website <noreply@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: noreplt@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n";

if ($_POST['send']){
mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
echo 'Message Sent.';
} else {

    die('Failed to Send');
} 


?>
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the form posts correctly? It could be that you misconfigured the email settings. And what happens when you press the submit button as it is now?

Comment: Your form didn't send any `$_POST['send']` variable in `post` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);`
here you used $header

Comment: I have changes this but am still getting the following error Undefined index: send in \mail.php on line 31

Comment: use this if ($_POST['submit']){